# How to make Windows Share browse-able in PHP?

Tags: php, windows

I need to show a windows share (\\something\other) as a browesable directory in php. How can I do that? 
If I point the link to the windows share, I get something like file://something/other in the link, which I could open only in IE. What is the solution to make it work across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all share the folder to public, with atleast Read(or what ever permission you want to give)

and this will be done using your web Server(ex. Apache, Samba, etc.)

configure the same shared directory in the server by adding Virtual Path, and then

Allow directory browsing for the same "Virtual Directory".

then try the virtual directory using browser,

I hope this will help you :)